# Same box-shadow looks different in Chromium and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, chromium, box-shadow

I'm to create arrow with `box-shadow` using css, but have a problem with shadows in Firefox. It looks different with Chromium. As you can see on images attached below, on Firefox we have an additional shadow on the right side. How to make it looks the same ?

Firefox 60.0.1:

[image: Firefox 60.0.1]

Chromium Version 66.0.3359.181:

[image: Chromium Version 66.0.3359.181]

`box-shadow: -6px 6px 10px -6px #1111;`

Comment: share the full code, am pretty sure it has nothing to do with shadow but something else

Comment: Can't replicate (see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/JZKBVx)) - this works fine in Firefox 60 and Chrome 66.

Comment: Seems like a `z-index` issue.

Comment: thanks Brian, couldn't fix it this way. So i fixed it using :before element, and just put it over hidden side of triangle :)